# How to make each sentence in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an fuctions in JS like below.

```
  manager.addDocument('en', 'bye bye take care', 'greetings.bye');
  manager.addDocument('en', 'okay see you later', 'greetings.bye');
  manager.addDocument('en', 'bye for now', 'greetings.bye');
  manager.addDocument('en', 'i must go', 'greetings.bye');
  manager.addDocument('en', 'hello', 'greetings.hello');
  manager.addDocument('en', 'hi', 'greetings.hello');
  manager.addDocument('en', 'howdy', 'greetings.hello');
  manager.addDocument('en', "I'm home now", 'greetings.arrival');
```

And I changed this into json file.

```
 const bags = [
    { language: 'en', saying: 'bye bye take care', intent: 'greetings.bye' },
    { language: 'en', saying: 'okay see you later', intent: 'greetings.bye' },
    { language: 'en', saying: 'bye for now', intent: 'greetings.bye' },
    { language: 'en', saying: 'i must go', intent: 'greetings.bye' },
    { language: 'en', saying: 'hello', intent: 'greetings.hello' },
    { language: 'en', saying: 'hi', intent: 'greetings.hello' },
    { language: 'en', saying: 'howdy', intent: 'greetings.hello' },
    { language: 'en', saying: "I'm home now", intent: 'greetings.hello' }
  ];
  for (let i; i < bags.length; i += 1) {
    manager.addDocument(bas[i].language, bags[i].saying, bags[i].intent);
  }
```

But it doesn't work with same way. How can I use json file well in this case? Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You have a typo at `manager.addDocument(bas[i].language, bags[i].saying, bags[i].intent);` it should be `bags`instead of `bas[i].language`

Comment: @Yosvel Quintero You are right... Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES6 way of doing the same

```js
bags.forEach(({language, saying, intent}) => manager.addDocument(language, saying, intent));
```

Comment: Excellent use of [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this it would be [simpler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). in your original code, you did a typo in the first argument of `manager.addDocument` you wrote `bas` instead of `bags`

```
for (const bag of bags ) {
    manager.addDocument(bag.language, bag.saying, bag.intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You neglected to initialize the loop counter. Also you had a typo in `bas`.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < bags.length; i += 1) {
  manager.addDocument(bags[i].language, bags[i].saying, bags[i].intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two typos:

1. `for (let i; i < bags.length; i += 1) {`
   should be
   `for (let i=0; i < bags.length; i += 1) {`

2.
`manager.addDocument(bas[i].language, bags[i].saying, bags[i].intent);`
should be
`manager.addDocument(bags[i].language, bags[i].saying, bags[i].intent);`

Answer (score 0):

```
const bags = [
    { language: 'en', saying: 'bye bye take care', intent: 'greetings.bye' },
    { language: 'en', saying: 'okay see you later', intent: 'greetings.bye' },
    { language: 'en', saying: 'bye for now', intent: 'greetings.bye' },
    { language: 'en', saying: 'i must go', intent: 'greetings.bye' },
    { language: 'en', saying: 'hello', intent: 'greetings.hello' },
    { language: 'en', saying: 'hi', intent: 'greetings.hello' },
    { language: 'en', saying: 'howdy', intent: 'greetings.hello' },
    { language: 'en', saying: "I'm home now", intent: 'greetings.hello' }
  ];
```

`*` -  Array of Objects -> `const bags` on this example 
`**` -  empty Array of Objects
Using ES6

```
*.forEach(({key, key2, key3}) => **.addDocument(key, key2, key3);
```

Or older version

```
for (let i = 0; i < *.length; i += 1) {
  **.addDocument(bags[i].key, bags[i].key2, bags[i].key3);
}
```